# Set site webbindings to localhost-only and then restore them

Tags: powershell, iis

We need to run smoke tests during our Web Application's deployment script, which is a powershell script. Our site is hosted in IIS, and it normally runs with https on port 443 and requires authentication using OAuth. The smoke tests can't have test accounts, however, so they can't authenticate.

One option we are exploring is to disable authentication for the duration of the smoke tests and run them over http. I would need for our powershell script to do something like this (in pseudocode):

```
<save current webbindings for Default Web Site>
<set http on port 80 and localhost-only access for Default Web Site>
<execute the smoke tests>
<restore previous webbindings for Default Web Site>
```

I think that the [Set-WebBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/set-webbinding?view=winserver2012-ps) command should be able to do this, but the only example there is this one:

```
Set-WebBinding -Name 'Default Web Site' -BindingInformation "*:80:" -PropertyName Port -Value 1234
```

Does this command set localhost-only access? And how do I store the configuration before changing it, and then restore it afterwards?

Comment: You should be able to use the `Get-WebBinding` to store your values in a variable like $x, then `Set-WebBinding` for your smoke tests, execute, then `Remove-WebBinding` to clean up followed by a `Set-WebBinding $x` or something along those lines, right?  For the `-BindingInformation` property, could you use "localhost:443:" or does that break something on your server?

Comment: * means any ip ie localhost and/or any networks cards available to iis. Can you run `get-webbinding` and show current bindings on the site? Are you binding to an ip or `*`?